# Export Overpass-turbo Query Result to OSM File

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I have a tool which has input is an osm file, I ussually get the osm file by exporting map data from http://openstreetmap.org.

But now I have to get only data of roads so I use this query http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/2vM and it show what I need.

My problem is when I select "Export" tab and chose jOSM option for exporting to osm file, the site show me pop up :

> *Remote control not found. :( Make sure JOSM is already running and properly configured*.

I don't know how to configure JOSM properly. 
( Very sorry because my english skill is not good enough)

Answer (score 1):

In JOSM, click on the icon with the switches, then the remote icon on the left (above WMS/TMS)

There you can activate the remote control checkbox.

Your query is missing meta data, which is mandatory for JOSM. Auto-repair will insert `<print mode="meta"/>`.

Alternatively, change your Overpass query to `<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">`.

Then you can click on the `Data` tab on the right, select all, copy to clipboard and load it in an empty text file.